# Pythonのdataclassで値のバリデーションをする方法

Tags: python, python3

Pythonのdataclassにおいて、属性のバリデーションを実施したいときはどう書けばよいのでしょうか？
具体的には、下記のコードでnameに空文字が入るのを防ぎたいです。
Python 3.9.2です。

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class UserName:
    name: str

userName1 = UserName("") # エラーにしたい
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 557: Data Classes post-init-processing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#post-init-processing) を使う方法があります。

**validate_name.py**

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class UserName:
  name: str

  def __post_init__(self):
    if not self.name:
      raise ValueError('user name is empty string')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  userName1 = UserName("") # エラーにしたい
```

**実行結果**

```
$ python3 validate_name.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "validate_name.py", line 13, in <module>
    userName1 = UserName("") # エラーにしたい
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "validate_name.py", line 10, in __post_init__
    raise ValueError('user name is empty string')
ValueError: user name is empty string
```

Comment: アノテーションなので, `isinstance(self.name, str)` のチェックも必要かと

Comment: @oriri まぁ、そこは mypy にお任せで。